# Не работает загрузка файла через URL с помощью Download Manager (API 29)

Tags: java, android

Использую этот пример, но при нажатию на кнопку ничего не происходит, даже в логах. В чем может быть проблема или как её выявить?
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
  
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/download"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Download Content" />
  
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    DownloadManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.download);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf");
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
                long reference = manager.enqueue(request);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить request.setDestinationUri и android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,

Comment: Теперь показывает такую ошибку `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI: null`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в

```
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
```

Нужно заменить на:

```
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
```